# how to create user view with last login zero or never logged in

Tags: users, views

I am trying to create user view for those user who never logged in. For this i need a filter as last login is equal to zero.
Any body knows how to select filter as last login is zero.

When i used Operator equal to zero it shows a message
Invalid date format.

Comment: Drupal uses Unix time, what basically is the number of seconds since Unix Epoch (the number of seconds since January 1st 1970). That value should be equal to 0. Can you filter on that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after long search i got a suitable answer
If i put in operator is equal to value 1970. it gives me result
basically 1970 consider as a zero value.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for:

 filter: last login

 is less than: 1980-01-01

It should work